# Representations of compact unitary groups

Tags: representation-theory

I know that the representations of the compact unitary group in two variables $SU(2)$ are given by the symmetric powers of the standard representations.

Do we have such a result for the compact unitary groups of higher ranks? (I am principally interested in $U(3)$ in an explicit manner).

Comment: Is the natural representation self-dual for $U(3)$ and above?

Comment: The result you cite is for $SU(2)$, not $U(2)$. $U(2)$ has additional representations coming from powers of the determinant. In general the representation theory of $U(n)$ is well-understood but is more complicated than this, and can be described in several ways, e.g. in terms of highest weights or Schur functors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I edited my question, thanks for the comment. I would like to have a reference to get a precise description of these, do you know something of this kind?

Comment: See Chapter 6, Section 5 of this book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540136781 or you could look at Brian Hall's book. These books do everything in full generality, so you might have to backtrack a bit to get $U(3)$ specifically, but it shouldn't be too bad. The intuition is basically in line with Qiaochu's comment: you can work out the representations of $SU(n)$, but then you need to account for $\text{det}(U) \neq 1$ to get all of the representations of $U(n)$.